# Enable HTML button by time

Tags: javascript, html, button, time

I have an HTML button on my website:

```
<button id="upload" style="display:none;">  SIGN IN  </button>
```

I am needing to disable the button except for between the minutes of 25 and 35 and 55 and 05 each hour. If anyone can please help I would be most grateful as I can only find javascript for between two times and it only disable the button once a day, not twice each and every hour.

Many thanks.

Comment: There is no such function to work out of the box. You will need to re-iterate the approach you have found

Comment: Show us the code you're talking about and we might be able to adjust it in a way that it works for you.

Comment: This is the script I was looking at: `<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
var enableDisable = function(){
var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
if ((UTC_hours == 17) && (UTC_hours == 18) && (UTC_hours == 19) && (UTC_hours == 20) && (UTC_hours == 21) && (UTC_hours == 22)){
document.getElementById('upload').disabled = false;
else
document.getElementById('upload').disabled = true;
}
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
// -->
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of implementation :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
onload = function() {
    var elt = document.getElementById("upload");
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    if((minutes > 24 && minutes < 36)||(minutes > 54 && minutes < 06)) {
        elt.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        elt.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<head>
    <body>
        <button id="upload" style="display:none;"> SIGN IN </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but is there a way of doing it using the `<button type="button" disabled>` method please as I am already using the `style.display` elsewhere as the button only shows after another button has been pressed? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this function to check in between:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>   
onload = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("upload");
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    if (check_between(minutes,25,35) || check_between(minutes,54,06)){
        element.style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function check_between(minutes,n1,n2){ 
      if (minutes > n1 && minutes < n2){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }   
}
</script>
<head>
    <body>
        <button id="upload" style="display:none;"> SIGN IN </button>
    </body>
</html>
```